# Failed to launch hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I installed hadoop and hive on a Mac OS. I am able to launch hadoop and yarn without any problem. I can run `hadoop fs` related commands to operate files on hdfs. But I failed to launch hive process and got below error.

```
$ hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/libexec/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/libexec/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bhive.session.id%7D_resources
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:634)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bhive.session.id%7D_resources
    at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:251)
    ... 12 more
```

I am new to `hive` and not sure where I should look at. How can I solve above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding this at the top of your `hive-site.xml`

```
<property>
    <name>system:java.io.tmpdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hive/java</value>
</property>
```

Or changing the directory to some `/tmp/mydir` as its told in [Configuring Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration)