# Unable to launch Hive on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, hive

I installed Hive and Hadoop on my Ubuntu VM.

When I launch `hive` on the terminal I get this:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [jar:file:/opt/apache-hive-2.3.5-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory] Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to
>   class java.net.URLClassLoader
>   (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and
>   java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.(SessionState.java:394)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.(SessionState.java:370)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.(CliSessionState.java:60)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:708)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)

And when I launch `hiverserver2`, **http://localhost:10002/**, which is Hive WebUI, stays inaccessible.

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775450/failed-to-launch-hive).

Comment: What JDK version do you have? There is a known issue with JDK 11: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21237. There is also a this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897645/hive-appclassloader-cannot-be-cast-to-urlclassloader-although-using-jdk8 that seems to imply that hive shell script only works with JDK 8.

Comment: I am on JDK11. I can't see a solution on the link you mentionned

Comment: You'll have to install JDK 8 and either uninstall 11 or modify hive startup script, as mentioned here https://www.mostlymaths.net/2019/02/apache-hive-and-javalangclasscastexcept.html

Comment: I installed JDK8 and it worked perfectly. Thank you @mazaneicha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  @mazaneicha suggested, It is easier to do it with JDK8. I was on JDK11. So I just